# {discord.py 2.0] Manually trigger command cooldown

Tags: discord.py

Is it possible to manually trigger a command cooldown when it is called in another function?
Something like :

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(2, 3600*3 , commands.BucketType.member)
async def command1(ctx):
   ...

@bot.command()
async def command2(ctx):
   ...
   await command1(ctx) #OR await ctx.invoke(bot.get_command('command1'))
   #Then trigger command1 cooldown
```

Comment: Trigger the cooldown for who? The member who ran `command2`, guild-wide, or globally?

Comment: for the member who ran command2